# Django: правильная логика создания пользователей

Tags: django

Я создал кастомную модель User переопределив AbstractUser

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)',message="Некорректные символы в адресе почты. Допускается использовать цифры, латинские буквы и символы 'точка', 'нижнее подчеркивание'")
    email = models.EmailField(validators=[email_regex], unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,12}$', message="Некорректные символы или количество цифр. Правильный формат +71234567890.")
    phone = models.CharField(_('номер телефона'), validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17) 
    is_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone']

    objects = UserManager()
```

После этого создал профиль основного пользователя с почти 20 полями в модели:

```
class Profile(models.Model):           
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

Теперь надо создавать профиль клиента, в котором планируется только одно поле с именем. Как правильно сделать? Если я сделаю пользователя на основе модели profile то у него в БД и в админке будет висеть 20 пустых полей. Если создам нового по тому же принципу OneToOneField, то при регистрации будут создаваться 2 модели. В общем подскажите что бы на старте не допустить ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта могут быть правильными. Когда будет 2 модели будет немного сложнее код. 
Если у вас намного больше будет записей где 20 полей пустые, то наверно сделайте отдельную модель, если нет оставьте все в одной модели, место сейчас дешевое )